# JUnit issue while using Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito

I have created  multiple junit test cases with mocking the Cassandra CQLSession class using Mockito framework. When I run the individual test class the it works. but when i run the test suite as a whole, seeing below error for mockito
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession$MockitoMock$534112137 at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor5.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:48) at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73) at org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.ObjenesisInstantiator.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiator.java:21) at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.doCreateMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:360) at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:318) at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:53) at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:61) at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1949)`

Version details:

```
testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '3.8.0'
testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13'
```

also tried with mockito version 4.0, still same error. pls let me know is there anything I missed.

Comment: Just incase some one facing the similar issue,  issue resolved after the restart of eclipse .

Answer (score 0):

Just incase some one facing the similar issue, issue resolved after the restart of eclipse .

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in my spring boot project. Upgrading Springboot starter parent from 2.6.7 to 2.7.0 fixed the issue.